# Ubuntu doesn't detect TP Link TL-WN881ND Wireless PCI-E Adapter

Tags: networking

This is the first time I've ever used ubuntu properly so I don't know what exactly I'm doing wrong, but I'm currently using a tp-link TL-WN881ND wireless PCI-Express adapter to connect to my wifi network. The adapter works flawlessly in windows but when I view the wifi settings I just get a message saying "No wifi Adapter found".

I've tried installing the linux drivers from their website using the commands

make
make install

but I just get the following when I press enter after the first command:

```
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors 
scripts/Makefile.build:332: recipe for target '/home/cormac/Downloads/linuxdrivers/wifidriver/core/rtw_cmd.o' failed 
make[2]: *** [/home/cormac/Downloads/linuxdrivers/wifidriver/cor/rtw_cmd.o] Error 1 
Makefile:1551: recipe for target '_module_/home/cormac/Downloads/linuxdrivers/wifidriver' failed 
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/cormac/Downloads/linuxdrivers/wifidriver] Error 2 
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-44-generic' Makefile:1696: recipe for target 'modules' failed 
make: *** [modules] Error 2
```

Sorry for the terrible formatting but I do not understand this AT ALL. I've spent two days at this and I'm just considering formatting my drive and going back to windows.

Comment: `cc1: some warnings being treated as errors` means that the C compiler found a situation where it would normally issue a Warning, but, due to command-line options, has been told to treat Warnings as Errors. You didn't show us the Warnings/Errors.